# List files from directory C/C++

Tags: c, directory

After some research on google and stackoverflow I came to the conclusion to ask this question myself:

```
Is there a more or less portable way to get a list of all files from a directory?
```

I want to support a shortcut in my application where you can give it a directory from the command line and it traverses it and its subdirectories automatically. I am free to use C and C++ but don't want to depand on any thrid-party libraries if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Regarding the duplicate-question: I already found that one and tried it but the dirent.h wasn't working for me. That's why I wrote this. Also regarding C/C++: my application is currently written in pure C and I would favor a C-only solution but if a better C++ solution is suggested it would also be acceptable.

Comment: Nominating this question for reopening, as the provided "duplicate" question has answers that are now nearly 8 years old, and the C++ language has advanced since then, changing the correct answer.

Comment: As `C` and `C++` are different languages, the OP should choose one.  Until that time it's safe to assume this will remain closed.  Note that the `dirent` answer from 8 years ago is a good answer today in `C`.

Comment: @Xirema: OP asks for a C solution in the first place (that or the question is too broad asking for two different languages). And that has not changed in the last 18 years.

Comment: What OS are you using?  The answer is OS dependent.